# C# wrapper for NetworkIsolationEnumAppContainers

Tags: c#, pinvoke

How can I create a c# wrapper to call:

```
  [DllImport("FirewallAPI.dll")] 
        internal static extern uint NetworkIsolationEnumAppContainers(out uint pdwCntPublicACs, out IntPtr ppACs);
```

I'm getting a AccessViolationException (attempted to read or write protected memory) when running it like this:

```
        uint aux=0;
        IntPtr foo=new IntPtr();
        NetworkIsolationEnumAppContainers(out aux, out foo);
```

What's the correct way to Marshall it ?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, Are you using .NET 4.0?

Comment: You've only shown one side of the interface. You can't ask an interop question like that. You need to show both sides. The only function I found with that name has three parameters and lives in a different DLL. Did you write that DLL? And I urge you to stop naming variables `foo`. Use a real name.

Comment: They are defined here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/12/10/fiddler-windows-8-apps-enable-loopback-network-isolation-exemption.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your p/invokes appear to have been lifted from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/12/10/fiddler-windows-8-apps-enable-loopback-network-isolation-exemption.aspx

That article says:

> Their .NET declarations (as of the BUILD conference) are as follows:
>
> ```
> // Call this API to enumerate all of the AppContainers on the system 
> [DllImport("FirewallAPI.dll")] 
> internal static extern uint NetworkIsolationEnumAppContainers(
>     out uint pdwCntPublicACs, out IntPtr ppACs); 
> ....
> ```

However, the API changed before release. The released version of the API has an extra parameter and is located in a different DLL. The documentation can be found on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netfw/nf-netfw-networkisolationenumappcontainers).

You'll need to modify your p/invoke to use this API.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the correct pointer to latest API. here is the code that is now working:

```
        uint pdwCntPublicACs = 0;
        IntPtr ppACs = new IntPtr();

        // Pin down variables
        GCHandle handle_pdwCntPublicACs = GCHandle.Alloc(pdwCntPublicACs, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        GCHandle handle_ppACs = GCHandle.Alloc(ppACs, GCHandleType.Pinned);


        uint retval = NetworkIsolationEnumAppContainers((Int32) NETISO_FLAG.NETISO_FLAG_MAX, out pdwCntPublicACs, out ppACs);

        //release pinned variables.
        handle_pdwCntPublicACs.Free();
        handle_ppACs.Free();
```

Comment: The `GCHandle.Alloc` calls do not make sense, as you cannot pin local variables, only objects. You should be able to remove them.